# What can I use to match the searched content to the content in the bracket? rails regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is a search input field that asks for the gas which is shown below. The problem I have is there is a gas called Carbon Monoxide [CO] and if I input in CO in the input field, I get random gases like Nitrogen Dioxide [NO2] or Acetone [(CH3)2CO]. I understand why Acetone [(CH3)2CO] shows up because it has CO at the end, but I don't know why  Nitrogen Dioxide [NO2] shows up. Is there a way to make the input content only compare with the content in the bracket of @Gases, so if I search CO, I only get Carbon Monoxide [CO]?

I tried to put regex expression next to lower(gas_analytes.gas) to only get the content in the bracket, but it does not work.

Controller

```
@Gases = ['Carbon Dioxide [CO2]','Ethanol [CH3CH2OH]','Hydrogen [H2]','Hydrogen Sulfide [H2S]', 'Nitrogen Dioxide [NO2]', 'Carbon Monoxide [CO]', 'Ethene [Ethylene C2H6]', 'Sulfur Dioxide [SO2]', 'Acetone [(CH3)2CO]' 'Other']
```

Model

```
sensors = sensors.joins(setup_variable: :gas_analytes).where("lower(gas_analytes.gas) LIKE lower(?)", "%#{gas_analyte}%") if gas_analyte.present?
```

Comment: What do you think `sensors.joins(setup_variable: :gas_analytes)` is doing? And can we the relevant parts of your schema? Could you show what you get by adding `.to_sql` after the `.where`?

Comment: I get "no implicit conversion of String into Array" and sensors.joins(setup_variable: :gas_analytes) is combing the two tables together to search.

Comment: The problem is likely the join, not the where. We'd need to know the relationship between sensors, setup_variable, and gas_analytes. To see the SQL being generated try `sensors.joins(setup_variable: :gas_analytes).where("lower(gas_analytes.gas) LIKE lower(?)", "%#{gas_analyte}%").to_sql`.

Comment: When I tried, it worked. I get ```SELECT "sensors".* FROM "sensors" INNER JOIN "setup_variables" ON "setup_variables"."sensor_id" = "sensors"."id" INNER JOIN "gas_analytes" ON "gas_analytes"."setup_variable_id" = "setup_variables"."id" WHERE  (lower(gas_analytes.gas) LIKE lower('%CO%')) ORDER BY "sensors"."name" ASC``` but I don't know how to use. How can I use?

Comment: Seeing the SQL is useful for debugging what's really going on, thank you it's a great help. You said you're getting random gases, but you're selecting for sensors. After you run the query, how are you getting the gases? `sensor.gas_analytes`? Do you want just the matching gases, or do you want the sensors with matching gases?

Comment: I'm using sensor.gas_analytes and I want the sensors with matching gases.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have something like this:

```
class Sensor
  has_many :setup_variables
  has_many :gas_analytes, through: :setup_variables
end

class SetupVariable
  belongs_to :sensor
  has_many :gas_analytes
end

class GasAnalytes
  belongs_to :setup_variable
  has_one :sensor, through: :setup_variable
end
```

You're selecting Sensors which have at least one matching GasAnalyte. But you get the whole Sensor object and all its associated GasAnalytes. When you check `sensor.gas_analytes` you'll get all the sensor's associated GasAnalytes, not just the ones you matched for.

If you just want to find matching GasAnalytes, select for them.

```
gas_analytes = GasAnalytes.where("lower(gas) LIKE lower(?)", "%#{gas_analyte}%")
```

Then, assuming you have your relationships set up correctly, you can ask each what their sensor is. `gas_analyte.sensor`.

Comment: I think I'll have the same problem, but thank you for the response!